# Why doesn't the sys.exit() terminate the script

Tags: python, python-3.x

when typing NO or N the file just keeps running, why?

```
while True:
        game_choice = input('Do you want to play? ').lower()

    if game_choice == 'yes' or 'y':
        break
    elif game_choice == 'no' or 'n':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Please answer only Yes/y or No/n')
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

your or statement is not correct `or y` will always be true, try this:

```
import sys

while True:
    game_choice = str(input('Do you want to play? ')).lower()
    if game_choice == 'yes' or game_choice == 'y':
        print("yes")
        break
    elif game_choice == 'no' or game_choice == 'n':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Please answer only Yes/y or No/n')
        continue
```

or a better version:

```
import sys

while True:
    game_choice = str(input('Do you want to play? ')).lower()
    if game_choice in ['yes', 'y']:
        print("yes")
        break
    elif game_choice in ['no', 'n']:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Please answer only Yes/y or No/n')
        continue
```